# PostgreSQL: Compare strings in the same column but in different series (rows)

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table generated with a subquery that applies many different filters.

```
  | project
1 | Hello
2 | Hello 2.0
3 | Ordinary Sheep
4 | Sheep
```

The next step is to remove projects with very similar names (for example, if a project has the same name but followed by a 2.0).

In this case I need my query to remove `Project 2.0` from the results. This little issue is more challenging than I expected.

My best bet seems to be this one bellow where I correctly identify the project that should be excluded, but if I invert the operation I end up with duplicated data because due to the self join.

```
SELECT 
    q1.name,
    q2.name
FROM subquery q1
JOIN subquery q2 ON q1.name LIKE q2.name || '%'
WHERE q1.id <> q2.id;
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can match the first occurrence of a digit in a project and exclude everything after that.Then apply `RTRIM` and `DISTINCT` over it. This will however not work if the project name itself has a number in it.

```
with s as 
( 
   --your query that you have inside sub-query
)
select DISTINCT RTRIM(regexp_replace(project, '^([^\d]+)\d.*$','\1')) from s;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1d8921a0ca543f4fd15a619de71e6b55)